# Distributed Logging in EKS with Fluent-Bit To S3 Buckets

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I am trying to setup a distributed logging environment in EKS,

Application Deployment includes following components :

```
- EKS 1.25
- Spring Boot App
- Fluent-Bit (Deployed as a DaemonSet)
- S3 output plug-in
```

Fluent-Bit Daemonset Pod's are running with a ServiceAccount that is associated with an IAM Role with attached policy - 'S3FullAcessPolicy'.

```
Name:                fluent-bit-s3-token
Namespace:           bootapp
Labels:              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=eksctl
Annotations:         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-token
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

```
$ aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name fluent-bit-s3-full-access-token
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
        }
    ]
}
```

In Fluent-Bit Config Map, I have the following configuration for Input, Parser and Output

```
fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020
        
    input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser            docker
        Docker_Mode       On
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Trim      On
        Labels              On
        annotations         Off
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  Off
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Keep_Log            On
        
   output-s3.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
         Name   s3
         Match  *
         bucket bootapp-logs
         region ap-southeast-1
         upload_timeout 3m
         role_arn              eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn:arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-token
         s3_key_format         /$TAG[2]/$TAG[0]/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S
         s3_key_format_tag_delimiters .-_
```

Fluent-Bit DaemonSet is deployed using Helm.

Pod Yaml looks as follows :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: fluent-bit
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluent-bit
    controller-revision-hash: 6f475c7df
    pod-template-generation: "18"
  name: fluent-bit-d2m8m
  namespace: bootapp
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: DaemonSet
    name: fluent-bit
    uid: 77ae0241-fa92-419b-a6c8-0168a34f923d
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchFields:
          - key: metadata.name
            operator: In
            values:
            - ip-10-0-96-201.xxxxxxx.compute.internal
  containers:
  - args:
    - --workdir=/fluent-bit/etc
    - --config=/fluent-bit/etc/conf/fluent-bit.conf
    command:
    - /fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit
    env:
    - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
      value: regional
    - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      value: ap-southeast-1
    - name: AWS_REGION
      value: ap-southeast-1
    - name: AWS_ROLE_ARN
      value: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-token
    - name: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
      value: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
    image: cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.8
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: fluent-bit
    ports:
    - containerPort: 2020
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /api/v1/health
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/conf
      name: config
    - mountPath: /var/log
      name: varlog
    - mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
      name: varlibdockercontainers
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/machine-id
      name: etcmachineid
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-85z2d
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount
      name: aws-iam-token
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: ip-10-0-96-201.xxxxxxxxxx.compute.internal
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: fluent-bit-s3-token
  serviceAccountName: fluent-bit-s3-token
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - name: aws-iam-token
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          audience: sts.amazonaws.com
          expirationSeconds: 86400
          path: token
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: fluent-bit-config
    name: config
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/log
      type: ""
    name: varlog
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      type: ""
    name: varlibdockercontainers
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/machine-id
      type: File
    name: etcmachineid
  - name: kube-api-access-85z2d
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-04T02:54:29Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-04T02:54:34Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-04T02:54:34Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-04T02:54:29Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://5e75cc0ce4c48c59f6d4ae4181c020d9b13923d3c53b3d5710fc1838d822aa89
    image: cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.8
    imageID: cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit@sha256:1c8bdb90eb65902a65b7cd32126a621690dc36128fef78951775afbe37dfa01f
    lastState: {}
    name: fluent-bit
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2023-08-04T02:54:32Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.96.201
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.0.121.192
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.0.121.192
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2023-08-04T02:54:29Z"
```

In the fluent bit DaemonSet Pod's logs, I can see the following error :

***ERROR***

```
[2023/08/04 03:47:13] [error] [aws_credentials] STS assume role request failed
[2023/08/04 03:47:13] [ warn] [aws_credentials] No cached credentials are available and a credential refresh is already in progress. The current co-routine will retry.
[2023/08/04 03:47:13] [error] [signv4] Provider returned no credentials, service=s3
[2023/08/04 03:47:13] [error] [aws_client] could not sign request
```

**UPDATE :**

Switching on the Debug Logging.

Fluent-Bit Settings Modified :

```
    
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     debug
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020
```

The issue was identified as, insufficient K8S RBAC permissions to the ServiceAccount.

Following YAML fix that problem.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-read
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-read
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluent-bit-read
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluent-bit-s3-token
  namespace: bootapp
---
```

However, now logs are indicating that, Fluent-Bit is not able to parse the STS Response:

**ERROR (NEW) :**

```
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_client] auto-retrying
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #100 to s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 has been assigned (recycled)
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_credentials] Requesting credentials from the STS provider..
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_credentials] STS Provider: Refreshing credential cache.
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_credentials] Calling STS..
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #83 to sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 is connected
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_credentials] Requesting credentials from the EKS provider..
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [http_client] server sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 will close connection #83
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_client] sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com: http_do=0, HTTP Status: 400
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_client] Unable to parse API response- response is not valid JSON.
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_client] Unable to parse API response- response is not valid JSON.
[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [debug] [aws_credentials] STS raw response: 
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn:arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-token is invalid</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>b29f7d24-aa70-4cd3-bae4-e94832ff96a6</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>

[2023/08/04 05:53:04] [error] [aws_credentials] STS assume role request failed
```

Comment: What does the trust policy of your role look like?

Comment: Actually I got it working eventually. Looks like fluentbit in EKS operates with IAM Role Chaining. Your serviceaccount is assigned Role1, which can assume the role that allows you to preform S3 operations. I will soon update with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent-Bit Log collector forwarding logs to S3 for long term storage, Deployed in EKS, operates with the concept of
IAM Role Chaining.
Typically, Within Fluent-bit Output Configurations, for S3 output plug-in, you will configure an IAM Role that fluent-bit pod will assume() while uploading the collected logs to the S3 Bucket.

```
Ex :
     [OUTPUT]
         Name   s3
         Match  *
         bucket bootapp-logs
         region ap-southeast-1
         upload_timeout 3m
         role_arn              arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-role
         s3_key_format         /$TAG[2]/$TAG[0]/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S
         s3_key_format_tag_delimiters .-_
```

However the fluent-bit pod deployed in EKS will use the IAM credentials assigned to the Pod to perform this 'AssumeRole' API call.Hence, the solution that worked for me required the fluent-bit pod to be launched with a ServiceAccount associated with an IAM Role ("fluent-bit-pod-role") that can assume the "fluent-bit-s3-full-access-role" IAM Role.

Note: The "fluent-bit-pod-role" is created automatically when you use the "eksctl create iamserviceaccount" to create the serviceaccount for your pod.

1. Create an Assume Role Policy, granting permission to assume the role to perform s3 uploads.

```
aws iam create-policy \
    --policy-name fluent-bit-pod-assume-role-policy \
    --policy-document \
'{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/fluent-bit-s3-full-access-role"
        }
    ]
}'

$ export POLICY_ARN=$(aws iam list-policies --region ap-southeast-1 --output text --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`fluent-bit-pod-assume-role-policy`].Arn')
```

2. Allow anyone within your account to assume the s3-full-access-role.
   (Should be more granular to follow the principal of least privilege)

```
aws iam create-role \
  --role-name fluent-bit-s3-full-access-role \
  --assume-role-policy-document \
  '{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:root"
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

3. Attach the necessary permissions to the policy. For Similicity, I have just used the broad "S3FullAccessPolicy".

```
$ aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess --role-name fluent-bit-s3-full-access-role
```

4. Create the serviceaccount to be used by the Fluent-Bit Pods.

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount fluent-bit-s3-token --namespace logging --role-name=fluent-bit-pod-role --attach-policy-arn ${POLICY_ARN} --cluster bootapp-eks-cluster --region ap-southeast-1 --approve --override-existing-serviceaccounts
```